# How can I sort by a DateTimeField and choose distinct elements based on a ForeignKey?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL as database for my Django project. I have the following models:

```
class Food(models.Model):
    """Stores a food entry"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image_id = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.TextField()

class SurveyResult(models.Model):
    """Stores survey food result based on emoji and personality"""
    emoji = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    personality = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    food = models.ForeignKey(Food, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    rating = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
```

I need to write a query sorted by  `'-timestamp'`, and just get distinct values for `'food'`. This is my what I have tried:

```
SurveyResult.objects.order_by('-timestamp').distinct('food')
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> ProgrammingError: SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
>   LINE 1: SELECT DISTINCT ON ("recommender_surveyresult"."food_id") "r...

I have read several answers from several questions, and I found an answer that basically says to do something like this:

```
SurveyResult.objects.order_by('food', '-timestamp').distinct('food')
```

However, I am not getting what I want that is the latest `SurveyResult` objects that have a distinct `food`.

How can I achieve this?

Let's suppose I have the following table in my database:

```
# surveyresults
id emoji personality food timestamp            rating
1  :)    Famous US     1  2018-01-01 - 9:00      1
2  XD    Famous CN     3  2018-01-01 - 9:10      2
3  :)    Famous NZ     5  2018-01-01 - 9:15      3
4  :(    Famous FR     5  2018-01-01 - 9:35      4
5  XD    Famous US     1  2018-01-01 - 9:45      5
6  ;)    Famous JP     4  2018-01-01 - 9:55      5
7  :o    Famous SP     4  2018-01-01 - 10:00     5
```

The query should give me the folowing:

```
id emoji personality food timestamp            rating
7  :o    Famous SP     4  2018-01-01 - 10:00     5
5  XD    Famous US     1  2018-01-01 - 9:45      5
4  :(    Famous FR     5  2018-01-01 - 9:35      4
2  XD    Famous CN     3  2018-01-01 - 9:10      2
```

I would also like to know if it is possible to achieve this just with one query.

Comment: Aren't those of the latest attempt the right objects, just not in the right order?

Comment: @shwobaseggl, I will update my question providing what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using `subquery` as below,

```
SurveyResult.objects.filter(
    id__in=SurveyResult.objects.order_by('food', '-timestamp').distinct('food')
).order_by('-timestamp')
```

**Explanation:**

So basically `subquery` involve evaluation of more than one `query`, in your case, we are evaluating two queries. The SQL for the above `queryset` would look like,

```
SELECT "id", "emoji", "personality", "food", "timestamp", "rating"
FROM "appname_surveyresult"
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT "id", DISTINCT ON ("food") 
    FROM "appname_surveyresult"
    ORDER BY "food" ASC, "timestamp" DESC 
)
ORDER BY "timestamp" DESC
```

So firstly the inner (just like mathematics) query evaluates whose result becomes the input to the outer query resulting in **the latest of latest among the distinct**. Read [this](https://www.dofactory.com/sql/subquery) for more.

Comment: it seems you query works, but it is not giving me what I want. I will update my question.

Comment: Fantastic! gave me the result before I finish updating my question. Thanks!

Comment: is it too much to ask you to provide a further explanation in your answer?

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf Happy to help. There you go with the explanation, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider adding a meta class to your SurveyResults model and then specify your order there

```
class SurveyResult(models.Model):
    ...

   class Meta:
        ordering = ('-timestamp',)
```

Comment: I did not want to use this, but I think your answer is valid, and I will upvote it.